# Ansible keeps moving pip

Tags: python, ansible

Im installing `python3` on `amazon linux2` with `ansible` using the below snippet:

```
    - name: amazon-linux-extras
      shell: "amazon-linux-extras install docker=18.06.1 python3.8 -y"
```

Then i try and do a pip upgrade (or any pip install for that matter)

```
    - name: pip_upgrade
      pip:
        name: "{{ packages }}"
        executable: /usr/local/bin/pip3
        state: latest
      vars:
        packages:
        - pip
        - setuptools
```

and it cant find pip3.

I run `which pip3` and the location keeps alternating between

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

Is there a way to fix to a specific location? I was hoping to side step by just calling `executable: pip3` but it again returns

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to find any of pip3 to use.  pip needs to be installed."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you write the output of `which pip3` to a var. within the tasks file, and refer to that as the executable?

```
- name: pip_upgrade
  pip:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
    executable: "{{ pip_bin }}"
    state: latest
  vars:
    pip_bin: which pip3
    packages:
    - pip
    - setuptools
```